Plot multiple Pandas Dataframes with Timedelta Index with different Samplerates
i'm using Pandas to plot some data and i have the following Code to plot Multiple Pandas Dataframes on a common x-axis:
    #place where my data comes from    
    list_of_dfs = [instance.parent_perspective.associated[expression] for expression in instance.parent_perspective.associated] 

    figure, axis = plt.subplots(len(list_of_dfs), 1, sharex=True)

    for dataframe in list_of_dfs:
        print(dataframe)

    for i, dataframe in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
        ax = dataframe.plot(ax=axis[i])


The dataframes are indexed by Pandas Timedelta objects and come in different sampling rates, so the differences between the Timedelta objects are different for some of the dataframes.
The code runs when i order the dataframes by samplerate from lower to higher, but when ordered from higher to lower samplerate, i get the following Error:
File "C:\Users\[me]\..\[my_script].py", line 110, in [my_script]
    ax = dataframe.plot(ax=axis[i])
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1030, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 71, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 501, in generate
    self._make_plot(fig)
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 1544, in _make_plot
    newlines = plotf(
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 1589, in _ts_plot
    freq, data = maybe_resample(data, ax, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\timeseries.py", line 84, in maybe_resample
    series.index = series.index.asfreq(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
AttributeError: 'TimedeltaIndex' object has no attribute 'asfreq'. Did you mean: 'freq'?

I'm assuming it has to do something with the way in which the pandas matplotlib plotting feature tries to marry common x-axes together if given different samplerates.
I'm also sharing the prints of my dataframes so you can make sure that i'm not handing over bad data.
From lower to higher samplerate:
                        value
0 days 00:00:00           0.0
0 days 00:00:00.010000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.020000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.030000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.040000    0.0
...                       ...
0 days 00:10:24.950000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.960000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.970000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.980000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.990000    0.0

[62500 rows x 1 columns]
                        value
0 days 00:00:00           0.0
0 days 00:00:00.010000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.020000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.030000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.040000    0.0
...                       ...
0 days 00:10:24.950000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.960000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.970000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.980000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.990000    0.1

[62500 rows x 1 columns]
                             value
-1 days +23:59:59.999100  0.031557
-1 days +23:59:59.999200  0.032379
-1 days +23:59:59.999300  0.031419
-1 days +23:59:59.999400  0.032287
-1 days +23:59:59.999500  0.031857
...                            ...
0 days 00:10:24.998600    6.252964
0 days 00:10:24.998700    6.251458
0 days 00:10:24.998800    6.251105
0 days 00:10:24.998900    6.248893
0 days 00:10:24.999000    6.248886

[6250000 rows x 1 columns]

And finally, from higher to lower samplerate (this is the data that fails my code!). It's the same data, just with the faster sampled data moved to the first spot in the list.
                         value
-1 days +23:59:59.999100  0.031557
-1 days +23:59:59.999200  0.032379
-1 days +23:59:59.999300  0.031419
-1 days +23:59:59.999400  0.032287
-1 days +23:59:59.999500  0.031857
...                            ...
0 days 00:10:24.998600    6.252964
0 days 00:10:24.998700    6.251458
0 days 00:10:24.998800    6.251105
0 days 00:10:24.998900    6.248893
0 days 00:10:24.999000    6.248886

[6250000 rows x 1 columns]
                        value
0 days 00:00:00           0.0
0 days 00:00:00.010000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.020000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.030000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.040000    0.0
...                       ...
0 days 00:10:24.950000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.960000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.970000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.980000    0.1
0 days 00:10:24.990000    0.1

[62500 rows x 1 columns]
                        value
0 days 00:00:00           0.0
0 days 00:00:00.010000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.020000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.030000    0.0
0 days 00:00:00.040000    0.0
...                       ...
0 days 00:10:24.950000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.960000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.970000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.980000    0.0
0 days 00:10:24.990000    0.0


Double check your pandas/matplotlib version, make sure both are compatible. This seems to work fine in my hands for a quick check.

Also, try to remove sharex=True to see if this crashes the first approach

@mozway Thank you for your suggestions!
Upgraded both Pandas and Matplotlib to the latest version, no changes unfortunately.
removing the sharex=true fixes the issue but i feel like that just confirms my theory about the root cause, doesn't really get me closer to fixing it though :/

@mozway Actually, sharex = True does work.  Posted an approach with it. Let's see if OP makes it work on his data.

Here is an example of how to do this. Now the plot that I give is done on sample data. You need to use your own data
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_sample_data():
    t1 = pd.to_timedelta(range(62500), unit='ms')
    t2 = pd.to_timedelta(range(62500), unit='ms')
    t3 = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(0, 6250000 * 1000, 1000), unit='ns')  

    data1 = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, len(t1)))}, index=t1)
    data2 = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, len(t2))) + 1}, index=t2)
    data3 = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, len(t3))) * 2}, index=t3)

    return [data3, data1, data2]  

# Sample data
list_of_dfs = create_sample_data()
for i, dataframe in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    dataframe['milliseconds'] = dataframe.index.total_seconds() * 1000
    print(f"DataFrame {i} (first 5 rows):\n{dataframe.head()}\n")
    print(f"DataFrame {i} milliseconds range: {dataframe['milliseconds'].min()} to {dataframe['milliseconds'].max()}\n")

list_of_dfs = sorted(list_of_dfs, key=lambda df: df.shape[0])
print(f"Order of dataframes after sorting by length: {[len(df) for df in list_of_dfs]}")

figure, axis = plt.subplots(len(list_of_dfs), 1, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 10))

for i, dataframe in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    ax = dataframe.plot(x='milliseconds', y='value', ax=axis[i], legend=False)
    ax.set_ylabel('Value')
    ax.set_title(f"DataFrame {i}")

axis[-1].set_xlabel('Time (milliseconds)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

which gives
DataFrame 0 (first 5 rows):
                           value  milliseconds
0 days 00:00:00         0.000000         0.000
0 days 00:00:00.000001  0.000016         0.001
0 days 00:00:00.000002  0.000032         0.002
0 days 00:00:00.000003  0.000048         0.003
0 days 00:00:00.000004  0.000064         0.004

DataFrame 0 milliseconds range: 0.0 to 6249.999

DataFrame 1 (first 5 rows):
                         value  milliseconds
0 days 00:00:00         0.0000           0.0
0 days 00:00:00.001000  0.0008           1.0
0 days 00:00:00.002000  0.0016           2.0
0 days 00:00:00.003000  0.0024           3.0
0 days 00:00:00.004000  0.0032           4.0

DataFrame 1 milliseconds range: 0.0 to 62499.0

DataFrame 2 (first 5 rows):
                         value  milliseconds
0 days 00:00:00         1.0000           0.0
0 days 00:00:00.001000  1.0008           1.0
0 days 00:00:00.002000  1.0016           2.0
...

DataFrame 2 milliseconds range: 0.0 to 62499.0

Order of dataframes after sorting by length: [62500, 62500, 6250000]

and the following plot:

If you prefere the common time seconds:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_sample_data():
    t1 = pd.to_timedelta(range(62500), unit='ms')
    t2 = pd.to_timedelta(range(62500), unit='ms')
    t3 = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(0, 6250000 * 1000, 1000), unit='ns')  

    data1 = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, len(t1)))}, index=t1)
    data2 = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, len(t2))) + 1}, index=t2)
    data3 = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.sin(np.linspace(0, 50, len(t3))) * 2}, index=t3)

    return [data3, data1, data2]  

# Sample data
list_of_dfs = create_sample_data()
for i, dataframe in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    dataframe['seconds'] = dataframe.index.total_seconds()
    print(f"DataFrame {i} (first 5 rows):\n{dataframe.head()}\n")
    print(f"DataFrame {i} seconds range: {dataframe['seconds'].min()} to {dataframe['seconds'].max()}\n")

list_of_dfs = sorted(list_of_dfs, key=lambda df: df.shape[0])
print(f"Order of dataframes after sorting by length: {[len(df) for df in list_of_dfs]}")

figure, axis = plt.subplots(len(list_of_dfs), 1, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 10))

for i, dataframe in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    ax = dataframe.plot(x='seconds', y='value', ax=axis[i], legend=False)
    ax.set_ylabel('Value')
    ax.set_title(f"DataFrame {i}")

axis[-1].set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


which gives


Thank you very much for the example!
I got it to working and i was trying to plot against the index directly using your code, as i wanted the nicely formatted time format that pandas gives you on the x axis when plotting against Timedeltas. Interestingly this also worked.
Looks like i gotta figure out what the issue with my data is!

@Alrie Glad it helped. Once yuo've sorted out what the problem is and feel the solution I provided solved your issue, make sure to accept the answer so that it no longer is classed as unanswered. Happy coding!

actually i have to take my previous comment back. I forgot to consider your line sorting the data which means the faster sampled dataframe always ran last. If you actually make the faster sampled data go first again and don't plot against the seconds or milliseconds (as you are doing) but against the timedelta object directly, the error shows up again.
Unfortunately my application would greatly benefit from not being restricted to a certain unit for the x-axis but use the nicely formatted pandas timedeltas. So the problem is not really solved for me.

One obvious patch would be to just sort the plotting order by samplerate in my code as well, but that seems like a workaround that will disregard many edge cases and probably break the code in the future (As in: what if the samplerates are not exact multiples of each other? Whats with the total x-axis range? and so on).
So i would prefer understanding the issue in the first place.
